# org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlets

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: I/O error while reading input message; nested exception is org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:217)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:158)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:131)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:167)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
```

In our spring application, we are getting the above error. This error is mainly in POST API calls in a few cases, in GET request, there is no such error. All of these API doesn't involve any file upload, they are only interacting with DB or Redis. Our tomcat version is 8.5.40 and spring version 5.2.7. Sometimes request is timing out with 20 seconds, our Redis and DB timeout is in a few ms. what could be the probable reason for this error?

Comment: Did you use close() method to return resources?

Comment: I think you are not return resources when your job is done. also check your connection to DB(or Redis). the connection should return properly. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/connector/ClientAbortException.html

Comment: `java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket` it means your connection with client is invalid. Have you ever closed your browser or client before the job(using DB or Redis)?

Comment: Did you try to read inputstream before spring application read it.

Comment: Reading inputstream can cause this behavior

Comment: We are getting this error in the server, but the client (i.e mobile) dropping connection is not in our hands, how can we avoid such exception in the server, sometime this is even taking 20seconds i.e tomcat connection timeout.

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez yes inputstream is being read, what is the issue regarding reading input stream and how can this be avoided ?

Comment: If you can show the code that reads inputstream, maybe I can help you

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez I have similar issue that I get. I am using InputStream to read data like is.read(bytes) - where byte[] bytes = new byte[1024 * 4], and then closing the stream in a finally block. Any help here would be great.

Comment: @Han "... it means your connection with client is invalid": no it doesn't. It means the peer has closed the connection, or shut it down for output.